# How to render html source code inside a html document?

Tags: html

This is my codes

```
string="<img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\Help_1.gif\" alt=\"Help_1.gif\" width=\"882\" height=\"382\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\" /><img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\spikeyIcon.png\" alt=\"Spikey\" width=\"20\" height=\"21\" style=\"padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:middle;\" />";
```

However I've tried the tags `<p> <pre><code>`, just

```
<pre><code>string="<img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\Help_1.gif\" alt=\"Help_1.gif\" width=\"882\" height=\"382\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\" /><img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\spikeyIcon.png\" alt=\"Spikey\" width=\"20\" height=\"21\" style=\"padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:middle;\" />";</code></pre>
```

Save the code in a html file, open the html file by a Internet Explorer.

It becomes:(two images)

[image]

How can render my HTML source code inside the HTML page?

How about now, I think the question is clear now.

Please give me some upvotes to overcome some negative score, since I'm banned.

Comment: can you explain how you want to render it? by `php`, `javascript` etc ?

Comment: Simply output your HTML...

Comment: Tried `&lt;` and `&gt;`?

Comment: Can you show the exact and complete html that you used? "Open a page with this source code and you will see X. I want to show Y.". There is not enough information here to replicate your problem.

Comment: Is this a raw HTML file or is this snippet being generated somewhere?

Comment: @lc. Yes, it is a raw HTML file.

Comment: @Brad what do you mean?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Yes, render a text representing the HTML source.

Comment: @HyperGroups `echo $string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are attempting to render the html source replace all < with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;`.

For further reading look at [this article](http://wonko.com/post/html-escaping).

Comment: I see that,,, I saw `<with &lt; and>` a tag, that's a misunderstood.

Comment: BTW What' the English name of gt and lt? Left Tag?

Comment: @HyperGroups less than and greater than see this page - http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: If that's what you really want to do, use `htmlspecialchars()` instead.

Comment: @HyperGroups Please don't ask for totally unrelated support in questions. Stay on target and stick to the question you asked. :)

Answer (score 1):

**--after question edit--**

use `&lt` and `&gt` instead of `<` and `>`, otherwise `<img...` is understood as a html `img` element by the browser.

and no need to escape the `"` with `\"` you can just leave it

Answer (score 0):

**this is before your edit (which makes a whole new question)**

something like

html

```
<div id="foobar"></div>
```

js

```
string="<img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\Help_1.gif\" alt=\"Help_1.gif\" width=\"882\" height=\"382\" style=\"vertical-align:middle\" /><img src=\"/HTMLFiles\\Help\\Help\\spikeyIcon.png\" alt=\"Spikey\" width=\"20\" height=\"21\" style=\"padding-right:2px; border:0px solid white; vertical-align:middle;\" />";

$("#foobar").html = string;
```

and you can replace `\"` with a simple `'` makes it a bit more readable.